# setText doesn't assins value to all TextViews that are getting inflated

Tags: android

I have two layouts `notification.xml` and `notification_fragment.xml`.

`notification_fragment.xml` has got a TextViewwithin it.

`notification_fragment.xml` has got a LinearLaout of id `linear` within it.

Im trying to inflate `notification_fragment.xml` multiple times within `notification.xml` as you can see from the following code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container,
                false);

        linear = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, linear);
        for (int i = 0; i<= 10; i++){
            childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, linear);
            TextView txt = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txt.setText("welcome");
            txt.setTag(i);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

The problem with my code is that, it `txt.setText` sets the value of TextView as `welcome` only for the first view that is getting inflated whereas the remaining 9 views has got default values that I hard coded in my xml.

How to make all text views to display the text `welcome` ?

Answer (score 0):

finally i have figured it out by myself. Thank you for every one who tried.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);

    linear = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

        childView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, linear);

        TextView txt = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText("welcome");
        txt.setId(i);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

I just have to set the id tot the text views each time when Im inflating the views.

Comment: You need to add childView.add(txt);  in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use an if condition.

```
if(i==0){
 txt.setText("welcome");
}
```

2. You can use `do-while` loop
   3.

   ```
   childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, linear);
   for (int i = 0; i<= 10; i++){
      linear);
       TextView txt = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       txt.setText("welcome");
       txt.setTag(i);
       //  add this view to its parent view. i.e. here 'childView' 
       childView.add(txt);
   }
   return rootView;
   ```

Comment: why setTag method has to be invoked?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  there are some errors in your code.

Comment: there are multiple TextViews with same id. by setting a tag you can getTag();  for that particular view and differentiate between them.

Comment: Im just trying to inflate child views multiple times within parent view and Im trying to setOnClickListener for those child views